# how to fix "break outside loop "?

Tags: python, break

````
number = 12
apple = True

'''def quit():
    if guess == "quit":
        break
    print ("Exit")'''

while apple:
    guess = int(input("Write a number: "))

    quit()

    if guess == number:
        print ("Correctly")
        running = False

    elif guees < number:
        print ("Number greater than")

    else:
        print ("Number less than")

else:
    print("End of the cycle")```
````

Comment: please explain what you are trying to do

Comment: The `quit()` function does not have a loop, so you can't use `break` in that context.  Yes, you're _calling_ quit() from a loop, but that won't work.  Just take the three lines of code in that function and move them directly inside the loop.

Comment: first of all i would say: with quit function you want to see if guess == 'quit', the first problem is that if guess == 'quit' you can't put it in the int function (line 10)

Comment: I want to make a game in the cmd, so that the user guesses the number of the Apple, and add a function for the ability to exit the loop

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying to break out of a loop, through a function called from within the loop. This cannot be done. You can, however, return whether or nor the loop should be broken:

```
def shouldQuit(guess):
    return guess == 'quit'
```

And in your loop:

```
while apple:
    guess = int(input("Write a number: "))

    if shouldQuit(guess):
        break

    ...
```

However, `guess` can never be equal to `quit`, since you've cast the input to an integer

Answer (score 0):

```
def quit(guess):
    if guess == "quit":
        Return True
    Return False

while apple:
    guess = int(input("Write a number: "))

    if quit(guess):
        break

    ...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = '10'
while True:
   guess = input(': ')
   if guess == 'quit':
      print("let's quit")
      break
   elif guess == n:
      print('right!')
   elif guess > n:
      print('too high')
   else:
      print('too low')
```

i think this should work

Answer (score 0):

The way it is currently written you are going to get a ValueError if anything other than a number is taken by input(). So all these other answers are going to error out anyways without handling the exception.

```
 while apple:
        try:
            guess = int(input("Write a number: "))
        except ValueError:
            print('Exit')
            exit()
        else:
            ...etc
```